# Liferay 6 create 'Add Page' link outside of dockbar

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

Is it possible to replicate the 'add page' link outside of the dockbar?

It is possible to replicate the 'add application', 'control panel', 'toggle controls' and 'page layout' links outside of the dockbar by adding javascript to main.js.

This question hasn't been answered on the Liferay forums as yet so I thought I'd try here.

Answer (score 1):

The following are for Liferay 6.1 (earlier versions my differ but it's a starting point):

1. **Control Panel**

   You can use the following URL:

   http://yourliferaysite.com/group/control_panel?doAsGroupId={groupId}&refererPlid={plid}

   Where you replace **{groupId}** with the Group ID of the community
   you're currently accessing, and replace **{plid}** with the plid of
   the page (layout) that you're currently on. Note that the plid is
   **NOT** the Layout Id and can be found in the database in the layout table.
2. **Edit Controls / Toggle Controls**

   You need to add and remove the following CSS classes from the
   `<body>` tag.

   The classes are

   - **controls-hidden** : This CSS class hides the controls
   - **controls-visble** : This CSS class shows the controls

   These can both be added and removed easily using jQuery's addClass
   and removeClass methods.

   ```
   $('body').removeClass('controls-visible').addClass('controls-hidden');
   ```

   This will hide the controls, and the vice versa will show the
   controls.

   or using Alloy UI:

   ```
   AUI().use('node', function(A) {
       A.one('body').replaceClass('controls-visible','controls-hidden');
   }
   ```
3. **Add Page**

   I'm afraid this I also don't know how to do. It must be buried
   somewhere in the Alloy UI libraries but I can't debug how it works!
   Sorry!

Hopefully the first two will prove useful!